# jquery current parent and child selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a slight trouble in selecting the correct current `<ul> <li>` selectors

```
$('#menu > li').on('mouseover', function (e) {
    $(this).find("ul:first").show();
    $(this).find('> a').addClass('active');
}).on('mouseout', function (e) {
    $(this).find("ul:first").hide();
    $(this).find('> a').removeClass('active');
});
```

in the above code I can find the `<ul id="menu">` and its `<li>` and even its first `<ul>`

Now I want to find the first `<ul>`'s all children `<ul>`. Like finding `ul` with id first `ul` and along with that all the other `ul` inside it till the `ul` with image.

I have just added the id for reference I'm not going to use that id.

```
<ul id="menu" class="clearfix"> <li><a href="#">Categories</a>
    <li class="purple">    
        <a href="#">Design</a>
        <ul id="firstul">
            <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>    
                        <a href="#"> Photoshop CS</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><img src="m3.jpg" width="200"></li>
                        </ul>  
                    </li>
                </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>  
    </li>
</ul>
```

A jsfiddle for the above working https://jsfiddle.net/neerajsonar/yLtzrLm9/

Also I need a jQuery for it not using css selectors and using `ul > li > ul` this isn't working for me or else I might be using it wrong while trying.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you want.

Comment: Can you use `#menu` in selector? or `.clearfix `?

Comment: this: `$("ul").not("ul ul");` find the FIRST `<ul>` without using `#id`. Take care... this selector find **ALL** <ul> that aren't child of an <ul>.

Comment: I don't want to use css selectors. I want jQuery selectors for it. I have used #menu and using it I want to find the first UL inside it and add a class, along with that I want to find all the inner ULs and add a class to them too.

Comment: `$("#menu ul").addClass("someclass");` this add a class to each UL inside `#menu`

Comment: I don't want that class to be applied to all the ULs inside #menu. I want to add class to the first UL inside #menu and its respective inner child ULs

Comment: In simple words, in the fiddle i have provided, when i hover on Categories, I want Design > Photoshop > Photoshop CS , active/selected so that it shows all till the last ul when i hover on Categories itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80057/discussion-between-frogmouth-and-neeraj-sonar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I do something but there are a issue that i not understand:

take a look here.. http://jsfiddle.net/yLtzrLm9/1/

I edit your fiddle, so, right now: when the mouse enter in "Category" (or in an other element that has a ul like child) by default all of the first ul was shown.

... but there is but, if you select "category" > "Design" > "Illustrator" the submenu fadeOut. But if you do the same an other time all works fine. I don't know why. Try yourself.

#### my change:

the use of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead `mouseover` and `mouseout` to prevent double handler calling when you navigate the menu.

add a new class `_selected` that shown all the first  inside a li, it will place when you navigate to category first li and remove when you change to an other subcategory that aren't the first.

This:

```
if(!$(this).is(":first-child") || $(this).parents("li:first-child").length !== $(this).parents("li").length-1) $(this).parents("li").not("li li").removeClass("_selected");
```

is a check to determinate if the element below the mouse cursor is visible because are in the flow of first elements.

Sorry but my english is too bad and it's hard to explain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it gave me a direction to pursue and get the result. What I did was  I added 
`$(this).find("ul > li:first > ul:first").show();
      $(this).find("ul > li:first > ul:first > li:first > ul:first").show();
      $(this).find("ul > li:first > ul:first > li:first > ul:first > li:first > ul:first").show();`
So that it shows all the nested elements. And `children()` wasn't working because it used to go to the innermost without showing the parents so it used to not show. I'll be posting the fiddle in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

$('#nav .parent-item').click(function() {

```
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
    return false;

});
```

Demo : [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/QHr2r/1/)

Comment: No using children(ul) gives me the topmost that's the <ul id="menu">'s all children <ul>'s. I wan't the first <ul>'s all the inner <ul>s
And if i use it in this function 
    $('#menu > li').on('mouseover', function(e){}); it gives the same result as before using find('ul')

Answer (score 1):

Using Frogmouth's answer I made some changes. I added the following

```
$(this).find("ul > li:first > ul:first").show();
 $(this).find("ul > li:first > ul:first > li:first > ul:first").show();
 $(this).find("ul > li:first > ul:first > li:first > ul:first > li:first >ul:first").show();
```

the `children();` wasn't working because the it was going to the innermost child and trying to show where as the parent isn't shown.

I made a mega menu type structure that changes according to the sub menu items. the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/neerajsonar/4erto7c2/4/